# Google Timer :: what is "one raised to one"?

Tags: google

I only recently needed to use Google Timer and I was surprised to see this (highlighted in screenshot) and couldn't find any explanation in [Timer Help](https://support.google.com/android-one/answer/6143309?hl=en-GB) nor in [Android developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html)

Google search didn't help ( admittedly not deep). It sounds dumb but what is this *1 raised to 1* and how to use it ?

Moto X Play, 6.0.1

[image]

Comment: It doesn't look like 1 to the 1, it looks like 1'.  That is one minute.

Comment: @Chenmunka You are probably right but what is the significance? It appears irrespective of duration the timer is set to

Comment: Yes, if I knew the significance I'd have answered rather than commented.  Maybe it can give someone an idea.  I don't see it on my phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The button `+1'` will add 1 minute to the timer. It's a convenience function to extend the timer so that you don't have to stop the timer, add a little bit of time, then restart it.

I am not aware of any way to change the extension value. If you want to make drastic changes to the timer running, it's easier to stop the timer and start a new one with a different value. Otherwise, you are constrained by adding 1 minute at a time.

Comment: That sounds logical , is there a way to increment it?

Comment: Figured that out :). What i asked is - can we increase it to say 2 minutes ; it anyway asks you if you want to add one minute. From  a UX view, it doesn't add value by showing `1'` when that is the only value or can take. You can add if you know, meanwhile accepting your answer. Thanks